# Where to find information about LinkedGeoData ontology?

Tags: openstreetmap

**[LinkedGeoData](http://linkedgeodata.org)** is an ontology with information derived from openstreetmap. I want to query linkedgeodata to get administrative areas and points inside those areas, but I would like to know a bit more about the ontology before starting. I already ran a query to get all the predicates, what I want is real documentation about each predicate.

Answer (score 1):

You know https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/LinkedGeoData ?

But just as hint, the usual way is to use an OSM dump or calling an (read only) API and then use the shapes on the basic geodata as filter.

I'm not sure if LGD will help you to understand OSM tagging (schemas, tag evolution and the current local use of the communities). IMHO it makes more sense to have a look at http://wiki.osm.org or getting in [contact to the (local) community](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contact). You might also consult http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org for a statistical POV, but this needs usually background knowledge for good interpretation.